# Initialize an array of lists of a list with c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, syntax

I am trying to initialize an array of lists of a list declared as a

```
List <List<int>>[] a
```

The problem here is that I do not know the syntax (I even do not know if the above syntax is correct).
I assume it to be correct because to initialize an array of lists declared as b, following syntax is used:

```
List<int>[] b = 
{
    new List<int> { 1, 3, 4 }, 
    new List<int> { 3, 4, 12 }
};
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Are you positive you need an array of List of List of `int`?  Seems pretty complicated...

Comment: Yes, it is an exercise I have to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of lists of list of int:

```
List<List<int>>[] a = new List<List<int>>[]
{
    new List<List<int>>()
    {
        new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5},
        new List<int>(){10,20,30,40,50}
    },
    new List<List<int>>()
    {
        new List<int>(){6,7,8,9},
        new List<int>(){60,70,80,90}
    }
};
```

Comment: This is what I looked for! Thank you.

Comment: Ahh, ninja'd!  You should add a second item to each `List<List<int>>`.  I've retracted my answer.

Comment: @D.Dave If you see this answer as the Answer, please mark it so.

Answer (score 1):

List is a dynamic array try to stick to one or the other.

`List<int[]> a = new List<int[]>();` is a list of int arrays, and is acceptable

but you could just have `List<int> intlist = new List<int>();`

and you can also do `List<List<int>> listoflistsofints = new List<List<int>>()`

and then `listoflistsofints.Add(intlist);`

all perfectly viable. the reason to use list and not array is that the size is dynamic, and you can use `.Sort()` methods to re-order the list, and adding and replacing elements is easy:

`intlist.Add(153);`

i hope this clears it up for you, let me know if you need to know more!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I would do it in another way but it is an exercise I have to do and you cleared it up!